# How can I start Plugin Development?

Tags: plugin-development, development-strategy

I have expertise in HYML, CSS, Basic JS and PHP so for plugin development what should I learn and where can I start plugin development?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read This - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn how WP is 'built' and functions. An understanding of that will help immensely.

Start at the Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/ . Lots of information about everything WP. And there are lots of googles/bings/ducks about creating plugins.

Start with a simple plugin that changes a minor thing (like changing the 'Howdy' to 'Welcome' on the admin screen. Then try a Settings page that stores things in the wp-options table. Again, lots of tutorials on plugins.

This is not an easy or quick 'journey', but lots of fun if you like tweaking and programming things.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Rick It's really appreciated and helpful

Comment: You are welcome. Just a note that a vote up and/or checkmark is always appreciated if an answer matches your question. Plugins are fun to make. Although frustrating at times....you get better at it, though.

Comment: The codex is being phased out. Use the developer handbooks: https://developer.wordpress.org

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - Codex being phased out. There is no reference to it on the main page of the Codex link I posted. But my answer is still valid, even with the Codex reference, which still has valid information. I'll reference the new developer pages from now on, though.